# How to eliminate an item from a list after using random.choice()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have a Python script with a list that I am trying to get random items from the list and put them in a variable, But I have noticed that when I run the program a few times (about 20 or so times) eventually it will print out 2 of the same items like "apples apples".

```
import random

list = ['apples','grapes','bannas','peaches','pears','oranges','mangos']
a = random.choice(list)
b = random.choice(list)
while a in (list[0],list[1],list[2],list[3],list[4],list[5],list[6]):
    a = random.choice(list)

while b in (list[0],list[1],list[2],list[3],list[4],list[5],list[6]):
    b = random.choice(list)

print(a + ' ' + b)
```

The while loop should cause the variable to contain a unique value each time but it does not.

Comment: If you intend to eventually choose all or even just most of the items in the list, shuffle it and pop items off the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while a in (list[0],list[1],list[2],list[3],list[4],list[5],list[6]):` is equivalent to `while a in list:`. Since `a` only ever contains values from the list, the condition is always true, and the loop will never end, and you will never reach your print statement.

To select multiple unique random items from one collection, use `sample` instead of `choice`.

```
>>> list = ['apples','grapes','bannas','peaches','pears','oranges','mangos']
>>> a,b = random.sample(list, 2)
>>> a
'bannas'
>>> b
'grapes'
```

Answer (score 2):

Kevins `sample` above is better, but I think this is what you tried to do with `choice`:

```
import random

fruit = ['apples', 'grapes', 'bannas', 'peaches', 'pears', 'oranges', 'mangos']
a_fruit = random.choice(fruit)
b_fruit = random.choice(fruit)

while a_fruit == b_fruit:
    b_fruit = random.choice(fruit)

print("{} - {}".format(a_fruit, b_fruit))
```

A few remarks:

- `list` is a [build in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) of python. Never name something list (or dict or del etc.)
- As kevin mentions that while loop is useless, and will run forever since it should always evaluate to true.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the list, I will remember that in the future.

Comment: random.sample() in kevin's answer seems to make the while loop redundant but you are right that was what i was trying to accomplish with the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative: If you don't care about the list, I'd use `pop`, if you do then you could make a copy and then use `pop` (I fon't know how you want to use your list).

```
idx = random.randint(0,len(fruit_list))
a = fruit_list.pop(idx)

idx = random.randint(0,len(fruit_list))
b = fruit_list.pop(idx)

print(a + ' ' + b)
```

Another way would be to scramble/shuffle your list, and then pick up the items one by one in order.

```
random.shuffle(fruit_list)
a = fruit_list[0]
b = fruit_list[1]

print(a + ' ' + b)
```

of use pop, again:

```
random.shuffle(fruit_list)
a = fruit_list.pop()
b = fruit_list.pop()

print(a + ' ' + b)
```